# Verify contract code on Etherscan when deployed with Ethersjs factory

Tags: contract-verification

I have contract compiled via `hardhat` and types generated via `typechain`. In my typescript code I am using `await MyContract__factory.deploy()` to deploy the contract.

Is there a way / library / etc to use the contract factory (which contains the ABI and bytecode) + the source `*.sol` files to verify the contract on Etherscan?

Ideally I would like to avoid dependencies on hardhat (`@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan`) so that verification can be performed with only the `.sol` and typechain files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you verify a contract on etherscan that is deployed by another contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27991/how-do-you-verify-a-contract-on-etherscan-that-is-deployed-by-another-contract)

Comment: @TalhaSajidChaudhary Sorry no

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly go through the plugin's [source code](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/tree/main/packages/hardhat-etherscan) to see what it does and adjust it to your needs. Or then check Etherscan's APIs directly and use those.

Comment: Thanks. Working on this now. Will release as a general solution if I don't find anything else along the way